# Query to group data by 5 second time intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has events that occur over a period of 1 hour.

```
2014-04-16 13:56:06.971 , 3474
2014-04-16 13:56:07.061 , 3609
2014-04-16 13:56:07.067 , 3617
```

The Table has the Time stamp and event ID

I am trying to group the data to have a count of the number of events that occurred with 5 second intervals, so it looks like this:

```
0-5 sec., 3
5-10 sec. , 6
10-15 sec. , 4
```

Thanks in Advance!
I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like that:

```
declare @Hour datetime = '2014-04-16 13:00:00' -- starting time

select 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (DATEDIFF(second, @Hour, EventDateTime) / 5) * 5)
    + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (DATEDIFF(second, @Hour, EventDateTime) / 5 + 1) * 5) + ' sec', 
    COUNT(EventId) 
from intervals
group by DATEDIFF(second, @Hour, EventDateTime) / 5
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, where you group by the seconds / 12

```
select 
  convert(varchar(5),[time stamp],108) as [hh:mm], 
  cast(min(datepart(s, [time stamp])) as varchar(10)) + ' - ' + cast(max(datepart(s, [time stamp])) as varchar(10)) as [second interval], 
  count(*) as total
from yourtable
group by convert(varchar(5),[time stamp],108), (datepart(s, [time stamp]) / 12)
```

or you could create a tally table with the start/end seconds and then join to it.